# Google Play InApp (Prime31, Unity) - User doesn't see products / product information not loaded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play, prime31

We have an app on the Google Play Store which runs fine, has a good amount of customers and a good amount of people who buy InApps.

Now one customer contacted us, because he can't see the prices of the product. So the QueryInventory thingy seems to fail. However for me and "all" the other customers it works.

What could cause such issues?

I thought about

- No installed play services
- Installation not through the Google Play Store
- No internet

However the customer can see InApps in other apps, has installed play services + has internet (verified via Leaderboards).

Is there anything from Googles side or from the customer device settings side, that can disable the functionality of Google InApps?

Comment: Do you have any information about the customer's device, country and android version?

Comment: Unfortunately our newest update seems to have resolved the issue. BUT we didn't change anything related to inapp, very strange. So it will be some of those issues we'll never know the cause (and solution) for.